# How to use php8 enum types in Laravel where conditions?

Tags: enums, laravel-9, php-8

I have a php8 enum type

```
enum OperationTypes: string
{
    case PointsAdd = 'points-add';
}
```

I need to be sure how to properly use it in Laravel database querybuilder.
For example:

```
Model::where('type', OperationTypes::PointsAdd)
or 
Model::where('type', OperationTypes::PointAdd->value)

Model::whereIn('type', [OperationTypes::PointAdd])
or
Model::whereIn('type', [OperationTypes::PointAdd->value])
```

What is correct way?

Comment: Did you test it out? Did you receive any errors?

Comment: Anything not working with these snippets?

Comment: Unless you dont explicitly define casts, you should put in the 2nd argument whatever is written in the database for column type?